# Wbkit WebView Crashes For Google Images OS 10.9

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, webkit

How can I load google images in a webview without it crashing? 
Unfortunately Xcode doesn't reveal much of the error except it shows 9 com.app.NSURLConnection.

However if I set the url only to be like [http://google.com] the code works without any problems but if I load the google images url the window loads up fine and then the webview loads up with the google images page and then after 3 seconds or so it crashes.

I have added all the necessary frameworks and import.

The environment is : Xcode 5.0.2
OS:Latest OS X 10.9

Here is the code:
    .h file

```
@property (weak) IBOutlet WebView *webView;
```

.m file

```
- (void)windowDidLoad
{
    [super windowDidLoad];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:
                         [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&site=imghp&tbm=isch&source=hp&q=moon"]];

    [self.webView.mainFrame loadRequest:request];
    [self.webView setLayerUsesCoreImageFilters:YES];

}
```

Comment: You might want to add some basic error checking and testing results of method calls for `nil` to figure out what's going on

Answer (score 0):

My apologies please ignore my question as I got it working by creating a new project in Xcode.